# What is the meaning and origin of "a ___ is a ____ is a ____"

Tags: phrases, redundancy

Over time I've seen phrases like:

> "a pound is a pound is a pound"
>
> "a year is a year is a year"
>
> "a gallon is a gallon is a gallon"

all following the template "a ____ is a ____ is a ____."

Now, to my understanding, this is to show/emphasize that "____" has a constant value, no matter what the context. However, it seems redundant to say that "a ____ is a ____ *is a ____*. The second time saying "is a ___" just seems unnecessary. What is the origin of this phrase? Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: The origin is "Rose is a rose is a rose is a rose" by G. Stein. It was parodied countless times by the likes of Hemmingway and Huxley. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_is_a_rose_is_a_rose_is_a_rose
This is easy to google, so will probably get closed.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/317178/an-x-is-an-x-is-an-x-what-does-this-mean

Comment: Yes, that does.